# how take second element from json

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, reactjs, server

I  want to take second element from second row from json. My code looks like this (look below).

```
class SItemBox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      customers: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/customers")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(customers =>
        this.setState({ customers }, () =>
          console.log("customers fetched..", customers)
        )
      );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.customers.map(customer => (
          <li key={customer.id}>
            {customer.firstName} {customer.lastName}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
export default SItemBox;
```

```
[
  { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
  { id: 2, firstName: "John2", lastName: "Doe2" },
  { id: 3, firstName: "John3", lastName: "Doe3" }
];
```

I want to take only "John2"

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you already did it. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes I take all data from backend in this way.
But 
    <ul>
   {this.state.customers.map(customer => (
   <li key={customer.id}>{customer.firstName} {customer.lastName}</li>
   ))}
   </ul>
this way I show all data, but I want to show only second element from second row

Comment: Shmili Breuer's answer is correct

Comment: You mean to write like 
<ul>
            {this.state.customers[1].map(customer => (
              <li key={customer.id}>{customer.firstName} {customer.lastName}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>

It show error " Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: I added a post for your case

Comment: @BurakGavas, thanks it's worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your case:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {(this.state.customers && this.state.customers[1]) && <li>{this.state.customers[1].firstName}</li>}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.customers[1]` will give you the 2nd in the array.

Arrays are 0 based so 1 is the 2nd element.